Approximating self-maps of $[0,1]$
Let $\mathrm{Inc}([0,1])$ denote the space of continuous, increasing functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. I want to find a countable family of functions $f_n\in \mathrm{Inc}([0,1])$
such that

Any $f\in \mathrm{Inc}([0,1])$ is arbitrarily close (probably in the $L^2$ sense) to some convex combination of the $f_n$'s.

One approach I thought of is to consider Fourier series on the interval, and then apply to them the following transform:
$T(g)(x)=\frac{1}{c(g)}\int_0^x e^{g(s)}ds$
where $c(g)={\int_0^1e^{g(s)}ds}$
Then to approximate $f$, you can take the Fourier series expansion of $T^{-1}(f)=\log(f')$, and apply $T$ to that.
Although $T$ is guaranteed to give a function in $\mathrm{Inc}([0,1])$, it is not clear to me that the resulting family of functions $T(\sum_na_n\cos(2\pi nx)+\sum_nb_n\sin(2\pi nx))$ form a good approximating family.

Is there a more principled approach?
Follow-up: is there an approach for the self maps of the disc $[0,1]^2$ fixing the boundary?


In what sense do you want ${f_n}$ to be orthonormal? It’s just not possible for them to be orthonormal in the standard sense if you want them to have range in $[0, 1]$.

I just removed the condition - I mostly mean that I don't want e.g. $f_1$ and $f_2$ be very similar, and orthogonality with respect to some inner product would probably guarantee that. But it may be too restrictive.

Linear combinations of $\text{Inc}([0, 1])$ are dense (in $L^2([0, 1])$ with the $L^2$-norm or in $C([0, 1])$ with the sup norm). So your condition is simply equivalent to asking for a sequence of functions $f_n: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ whose linear combinations are dense in the suitable sense. There are, of course, plenty of such things. $f_n(x) = x^n$, say. One especially useful theorem might be Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

I don't think they are dense in $L^2([0,1])$: there is no function near $1-x$, for instance. More importantly, I would like these approximation functions (and their 'combinations') to all lie in $\mathrm{Inc}([0,1])$, as in the example with the transform $T$. I imagine this 'approximating self-maps' idea must have appeared somewhere before, hopefully with a better approach

There are - $x^{1/n} \to 1$ in $L^2$, so $x^{1/n} - x \to 1 - x$ in $L^2$. (Note that I said linear combinations of elements of $\text{Inc}([0, 1])$, not elements of $\text{Inc}([0, 1])$ themselves.)

Also, a slight correction. The span of $\text{Inc}([0, 1])$ is not uniformly dense in $C([0, 1])$. It’s only uniformly dense in ${f \in C([0, 1]): f(0) = 0}$. But it is $L^2$-dense in $L^2([0, 1])$, that much is true.

In that case I would suggest editing your question to clarify $f_n \in \text{Inc}([0, 1])$. Also, if you want the “combinations” to also be in $\text{Inc}([0, 1])$, it might be better to instead ask about convex combinations (since $\text{Inc}([0, 1])$ is a convex set), rather than linear combinations.

Ah sorry, I misread. Note however that I'm not so interested in the span. Just want to approximate functions in $\mathrm{Inc}([0,1])$ by functions in $\mathrm{Inc}([0,1])$. Thank you for your last comment also, I will make those edits!

Also, your approach with the transform $T$, I should note, does not actually work as is. $T^{-1}$, in particular, is not well-defined, since any $T(g)$, as defined, must be absolutely continuous, but there are functions in $\text{Inc}([0, 1])$ which is not absolutely continuous, for example the Cantor function.

It’s also not clear why this approach with $T$ should work at all, since $T$ is not linear, so even if $T^{-1}(f)$ is well-defined, writing it in terms of a Fourier series does not help.

The approach with the transform $T$ also requires the functions to be differentiable on [0,1], which I would say is a pretty mild condition - this excludes the Cantor function. Not sure what you mean by the second comment: even if $T$ is not linear, I get an approximation involving a finite number of terms, and the result is as close to $f$ as I like, unless I'm missing something.

I wouldn’t say mild: Most of functions in $\text{Inc}([0, 1])$ are not going to be differentiable. As for linearity, two issues with that: Let’s say we write $T^{-1}(f) = \sum_n a_nf_n$. Then yes, $f = T(\sum_n a_nf_n)$, but that is not the same as saying $f = \sum_n a_nT(f_n)$, and unless you have the later equality, you still don’t have $f$ is approximated by convex (or even linear) combination of anything. Second, it’s not clear to me why $T$ should be $L^2$-to-$L^2$ continuous at all. Even if $\sum_{n=1}^N a_nf_n \to T^{-1}(f)$, I don’t see why $T(\sum_{n=1}^N a_nf_n) \to f$.

In fact, $T$ is not even defined on the entire $L^2$ space.
